# ReverseProxy not working on OSX El Capitan

Tags: mac-osx, virtualhost, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am attempting to access my plex web ui through a cleaner url. Currently, you can access it at http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org:32400/web/index.html. I want it to be at http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org/plex

Heres what I have,

> marvin:~ Marvin$ httpd -v
>   Server version:

```
 Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 22 2015 16:51:57
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:47
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

In

> /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
Listen 80

    # Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org
        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/marvin-error_log"
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/marvin-access_log" common
        ServerAdmin admin@futurehax.org
        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org/plex>

          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all

          ProxyPreserveHost off
          ProxyPass http://localhost:32400
          ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:32400

        </Proxy>
    </VirtualHost>
```

> /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Uncommented

`Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

and

`LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so`

My expectation with this current setup is to be able to reach http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org/plex/web, instead I get a 404.

I am a mobile software engineer, but this is one of my first adventures into networking and its beating me down pretty hard.

Comment: @r2Doeslnc,  Can you please check with:  `ProxyPass /web http://localhost:32400/web` `ProxyPassReverse /web http://localhost:32400/web`

Comment: you also need to have `mod_proxy` enabled.

Comment: Well, my mistake. With my previous config you can get to `http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org/web`. But you need:  `ProxyPass /plex http://localhost:32400/web` `ProxyPassReverse /plex http://localhost:32400/web`. This should work if mod_proxy is already enabled. You will need to restart apache whenever you make changes to a config file.

Comment: My module dump can be seen http://pastebin.com/EYaNc39f. I followed the instruction here - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-install-mod_proxy-module-into-apache-788406/ - to enable mod_proxy. You can see by the minor error with xml2enc that mod_proxy is at least being looked at.

Comment: Have you tried with the changes I suggested?

Comment: Yes. Those are the settings currently in place. Both http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org/plex and http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org/web lead to an apache 404.

Comment: Are you able to reach `http://localhost:32400/web`  locally?

Comment: Yes, and marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org:32400/web locally and remotely.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that you need to look at here:

1. Make sure that you are using the right config file. When I installed apache 2.4 on my El Capitan machine the main configs actually point to a different directory `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf`:

   ```
   $ httpd -V
   Server version: Apache/2.4.17 (Unix)
   Server built:   Nov 13 2015 19:31:42
   Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:51
   Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
   Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
   Architecture:   64-bit
   Server MPM:     prefork
     threaded:     no
       forked:     yes (variable process count)
   Server compiled with....
    -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
    -D APR_HAS_MMAP
    -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
    -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
    -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
    -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
    -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
    -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
    -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
    -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.17"
    -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.17/bin/suexec"
    -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
    -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
    -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
    -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/mime.types"
    -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf"
   ```
2. For reverse proxy you can simply use something like this:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass /plex http://127.0.0.1:32400
     ProxyPassReverse /plex http://127.0.0.1:32400

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Comment: See updated output.

Comment: Using your example, I get an apache 404. "The requested URL /plex was not found on this server."

Comment: Are you overriding your VirtualHost directive somewhere else? Seems like you may have another VirtualHost *:80 somewhere else too, that is basically undefining anything that goes to /plex  Thus you are getting a 404 (not found)

Comment: The config in /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf  has one that was generated by the OSX Server App. You can see the details about that here - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7231060

Comment: how did you install apache ? brew?

Comment: I created a backup of that config, and then deleted that virtual host and restarted apache. Still got the 404 error.

Comment: apache was already installed by osx. i used apxs to install the extra modules.

Comment: It is interestingly enough showing the plex favicon.

Comment: Could the problem be related to the "Allow folder listing" option I have enabled to allow me to serve files? Without that enabled, everything redirects to https.

Comment: @r2DoesInc yeah could be.  you probably have a redirect directive somewhere too if you are redirecting everything going to port 80 to port 443.  Do you have a VirtualHost *:443 directive somewhere?  It's hard to see without getting a full config with all included files.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are actually trying to access [Plex Media Server](https://plex.tv/) with a custom URL. As you can see, it is not just a website, but a media server. Anyway, here is a simplified configuration snippet that should work, from [here](http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-map-plex-media-server-to-your-home-domain/):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:32400/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:32400/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Plex-Device} ^$
RewriteRule ^/$ /web/$1 [R,L]
```

Please make sure that all the necessary apache modules are installed and check your apache error log to troubleshoot.

There seems to be a better solution offered by Plex. All You need to do is to register here: https://plex.tv/users/sign_in. And you can configure at your domain registrants to point marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org to https://app.plex.tv/web/app.

**Update**: From further investigation it appears to me your vhost entry is ignored by apache. Also when you try to access http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org, it lands on the apache document root.
What you can do is try with an alternative servername like plex.yourdomain.com or set up your vhost in user directory and see what happens. The beginning part of the article here can help you out: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/

Comment: Yes, that link is what I started working off of. I have more than just plex that I wanted to setup, so I was just attempting to get the basics understood so I could extend them to my specifics. Since using the plex.tv link would only solve the issue for one of my services, its not the route I really want to take.

Comment: I have edited my answer, and as I have mentioned, you need to investigate your apache log files. I have also pointed two basic configuration errors. You can post your error log too.

Comment: Mod proxy is doing SOMETHING. My `/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log` output from when I access /plex http://pastebin.com/huduKdLb. My `/var/log/apache2/access_log` when I access it, http://pastebin.com/JaS8duGN

Comment: Well it seems like an well known OS X issue. They have made some changes how reverse proxy used to work on the platform. Check here: (https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11503) and here: (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7231060)

Comment: Ive run into the SSL thing a few times after setting up some redirects, that was going to be next on my list of things to tackle. Im not sure how this relates to my proxy issue though, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Pls check the 2nd link above. There are also some hints to deal with the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a bit more than hints. From what I can see, what I have SHOULD work. I have updated my sites config in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/ to include the proxypass info, but still nothing. I do not have a custom sites file as mentioned in that link. That link basically recommends just restoring an older Server.app.

Comment: The logs seem to be reporting that its working. I do not know what I am missing. http://pastebin.com/nxJ5QT8c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31676/discussion-between-r2doesinc-and-bangal).

Comment: Could the problem be related to the "Allow folder listing" option I have enabled to allow me to serve files? Without that enabled, everything redirects to https.

Comment: I have noticed one thing, when you browse http://marvin.boldlygoingnowhere.org, it goes to your apache root directory. I think your virtual host entry is ignored somehow. Can you try with another hostname? like: http://plex.boldlygoinganywhere.org, you will need to add that in dns. Or see the beginning part here: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/, on how to setup vhost in user directory instead.